# OpenGL line drawing issue when using glDrawArrays

Tags: c++, opengl

When I am trying to draw a line using legacy openGL , lines are drawing fine.

```
glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < m_spline_cvs.size(); idx++) {
    glVertex2f(m_cv_positions[0][idx].x,m_cv_positions[0][idx].y);
}
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
```

[Correct Line Loop in Stipple mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc3Ee.jpg)

But when I am trying to use `**glDrawArrays**`. Something is going wrong?

```
std::vector <float> cv_tracker_target_line;

for (size_t idx = 0; idx < m_spline_cvs.size(); idx++) {
    cv_tracker_target_line.push_back(m_cv_positions[0][idx].x);
    cv_tracker_target_line.push_back(m_cv_positions[0][idx].y);
}
glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &cv_tracker_target_line[0]);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, cv_tracker_target_line.size());
glDisable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

[Wrong Lines drawn not in loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EOsa.jpg)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd argument in [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) is the number of vertices, but not the number of elements (floats) in the array. Each vertex coordinate consists of 2 components (x, y):

<s>`glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, cv_tracker_target_line.size());`</s>

```cpp
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, cv_tracker_target_line.size() / 2);
```

Comment: It worked , I was under an impression that this line : `glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &cv_tracker_target_line[0]);` , will automatically take grouping in consideration by 2, as in its first argument?